# Running multiple Postgress.app instances on Mac OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm in need of running multiple PostgreSQL versions for different projects.

At the moment I use Postgress.app and constantly switch between versions when working on another project (I have Postgress.app and Postgres-9.5rc1.app).

When running Postgres-9.5rc1.app it forces me to rename the app to 'Postgress.app' before things work, I also need to change my PATH settings.

I'd like to be able to run multiple versions on a different port, is this possible with Postgress.app ?

Comment: This sounds like you have outgrown Postgress.app which is just meant as quick and dirty way to get Postgres running on your can. You might want to consider using something like Vagrant to allow each app to run in its own virtual machine with its own environment and installed software.

Comment: Thanks max, I'll look into vagrant. I'm not sure this will help solve my issue because I'm also in need for 2 different postgresql versions in the exact same app (for testing new functions of postgresql releases), that would mean I need to configure 2 Vagrant VM's I guess ?

Comment: Yeah but setting up each vagrant box is pretty trivial - you just fork a git repo and customize the config file. You then run `vagrant up` for the repo working dir and it gives you a PSQL server which you can connect to via `postgresql://myapp:dbpass@localhost:15432/myapp`. The port is customizable.  https://github.com/jackdb/pg-app-dev-vm

Comment: Depending on what versions you could also use Homebrew's versions to install say 9.5, 9.4, 9.3 side by side.